# Cannot find get() method while using Picasso in Android

Tags: java, android, picasso

Need help with using Picasso lib in android studio. I want to use it to load image in ImageView.
So i added implementation in build.gradle and this was compled to my app. But there is no "get()" or old "with()" methods.

cant see get() in the list

[image: cant see get() in the list]

I found it by this way:

Picasso picasso = Picasso.get() is better, but not working

[image: Picasso picasso = Picasso.get() is better, but not working]

Still not working for me.

I just want the image will be loaded from phone storage. I can get the path, but dont know how to load into imageview.

EDIT: thanks for answer, but i should repeat it again, but now with your code

[code from 1st answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaxYU.png)

As you can see, it still not working.

Yes, it's implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'. I reinstalled Android Studio and it didn't work.

EDIT 2: just attached this picture to ensure you, im using the last version.

[version of Picasso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgnJ9.png)

Comment: What version of Picasso are you using?

Comment: You might be using older version of Picasso this is latest version `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using Picasso at class level. You should use it inside a method in `OnCreate()` in you are using `Activity` or inside `OnCreateView()` for `Fragment`.

```java
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {
   ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        Picasso.get()
                .load("image-resource")
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks you very much. Yes, all this time i just was putting it in the wrong place. Thank you again!

Comment: Please upvote the answer, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso doesnt need to intialize just directly do the syntax of lib

```
Picasso.get()
        .load("")
        .resize(50, 50)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Edited the question by repeating your code

Comment: `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` try this

Answer (score 0):

Check Picasso version switch to latest

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

or try to sync again

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i cant understand why it doesnt work